# mainWindow.on('close') gets called more than one time when I hide mainWindow

Tags: node.js, electron

I made a basic electron tray that opens a window when one of it's options is clicked. I check if I opened a BrowserWindow with a bool and create or show/hide the window.

```
const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
      { label: 'Open configuration menu', click:() => {
        console.log("called createwin");
        createwin();
      }
```

And createwin is:

```
function createwin(){
  if (windowshown == false) {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  console.log("Window has been created")
  windowshown = true;
mainWindow.loadFile('configuration.html')
}
else {
  mainWindow.show(); 
  console.log("Window has been shown");
} 
  mainWindow.on('close', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Window has been hidden");
        mainWindow.hide();
    })
}
```

When I hide/show the window it created like 4 times, my console looks like this:

```
called createwin
Window has been created
window has been hidden
called createwin
Window has been shown
window has been hidden
window has been hidden
called createwin
Window has been shown
window has been hidden
window has been hidden
window has been hidden
called createwin
window has been hidden
window has been hidden
window has been hidden
window has been hidden
```

after fourth time, it just stops responding. I can't even do

```
      mainWindow.removeAllListeners('close');
      mainWindow.close()
      mainWindow = null
      app.quit();
```

My problem is that my app completely becomes unresponsive after hiding the window for fourth time.

Update: The app becomes completely unresponsive after hiding the window if I start with `npm start` instead of visual studio code's debugger.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't call `mainWindow.hide();` in the  `close` event.

Comment: How am I going to get rid of that window without closing my app itself then?

Comment: call `mainWindow.hide();` then do any clean up you need to do in the `close` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a new event listener to the `close` event whenever you call `createwin`. Each of the event handlers is then run when the window is closed, resulting in the repeated `window has been hidden`.

You only need to add the event handler once, when you create the new window:

```
function createwin(){
    if (windowshown == false) {
        mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 1000,
            height: 800,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true
            }
        })
        console.log("Window has been created")
        windowshown = true;
        mainWindow.loadFile('configuration.html')

        mainWindow.on('close', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("Window has been hidden");
            mainWindow.hide();
        })
    }
    else {
        mainWindow.show();
        console.log("Window has been shown");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that worked. I was invoking multiple listeners as you said.
Now my application hangs when I close (hide) the window for the fifth time.

Comment: I can't reproduce your observed behavior - I just did it 10 times, then it got boring. Are you sure it's not some other part of your code that's messing up?

Comment: Looks like an issue on my end. When I start the app on visual studio's debugger, I can show and hide the window 2-3 times, when I start the app with `npm start` I can open it only once.
I even tried No Grabbing's method and made an ipc callback to mainprocess to hide the window. Results are same. 
It looks like I'll have to start over.

Comment: I just had to add `return 0;` in the end of `mainWindow.on('close', (event) => {`
Edit: Although I can open and close it more than 4 times, it stops responding after a while.

Comment: Update: This happens only when I run it from visual studio code, problem persists  when I run it via npm start

Answer (score 2):

Since you're calling `.close()` inside the 'close' event, It goes into recursive mode and loops "forever". I have a feel that `.close()` method its only a event trigger and you have to deal with the close process, so, instead of calling `.close()` inside the event, keep only the null line.

**Example:**

```
  mainWindow.removeAllListeners('close');
  // mainWindow.close() delete this line
  mainWindow = null
  app.quit();
```

Comment: Actually first line removes the listener for it so it can not loop as you stated